# How can update a table data by foreach loop in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

How can I will update a table data using multiple array, can't understand but trying.
Just one record update.

roaster_detail table will be update by $array4 data.
I added 3 images:

1. $array4(this data is new, for update roaster_detail table).
2. roaster_detail (this is old data, some field will be update id wise).
3. table records format (When I execute my code then update one record but I want to update all records).

my code is:

```
$array4 = array_chunk($array3, 1);        

foreach ($array4 as $result) {

    $roaster_detail = $this->RoasterDetail->query("Select * FROM roaster_details WHERE roaster_details.date = '$date_' AND roaster_details.shift_name_time = '$nishift_name_time3' AND roaster_details.status = 'back data' limit 0,1");

    if (!empty($roaster_detail['0']['roaster_details']['id'])) {
        $this->request->data['RoasterDetail']['id'] = $roaster_detail['0']['roaster_details']['id'];
    }
    $this->request->data['RoasterDetail']['emp_id'] = $result[0];
    $this->request->data['RoasterDetail']['roasters_histories_id'] = $data['id'];               
    $this->request->data['RoasterDetail']['status'] = 'up data';
    $this->RoasterDetail->create();
    $this->RoasterDetail->save($this->request->data['RoasterDetail']);
}
```

when I print **$array4** then view:

[image]

when I print **$roaster_detail** then view:

[image]

**Table records** :

[image]

My requirements is : update all records. Now update only one record.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What exactly are you trying to do and what is the actual issue? Please show us _all_ the relevant code, a _detailed_ explanation, example of the expected result and the result your currently getting. Remember that we know nothing about your code or what you're trying to do. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I want to update a table data id wise.

Comment: Please read the links I posted carefully and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Omar, please do not post images to convey data. Copy/Paste the data instead as text

Answer (score 0):

you should use saveAll(); instead of save() function when you using model in Loop

```
 $this->RoasterDetail->saveAll($this->request->data['RoasterDetail']);
```